# Remove particular object from array in mongoose document (Mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to remove one element from array in document 'dsrNote'

which has "_id" : ObjectId("58a5594bb77d2f1dd49e2986")

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("58a558efb77d2f1dd49e2983"),
    "userId": ObjectId("586356b199248d1517a6758b"),
    "dsrNote": [
        {
            "activity": "ajay kumar dogra",
            "_id": ObjectId("58a5594bb77d2f1dd49e2986")
                },
        {
            "activity": "ajay  kumar",
            "_id": ObjectId("58a55969b77d2f1dd49e2987")
                }
             ],
}
```

In above document i need to remove first object from dsrNote array

> i have tried this, but it is not working

```
collectionName.update({ "userId": "586356b199248d1517a6758b" }, { $pull: { "dsrNote": { "_id": "58a5594bb77d2f1dd49e2986" } } }).exec(function (err, data) {});
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: `{ $pull: { "dsrNote": { "_id": 58 a5594bb77d2f1dd49e2986 } } }` -> why `_id` value is not enclosed by double quotes? Is that a typo?

Comment: Double quotes is just formatted issue while posting , no error coming

Comment: @israel.zinc no error coming

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it is working on my case

```
DSR.update({"userId":req.ID,"dsrNote._id":req.params.id}, { $pull: {"dsrNote": { "_id":req.params.id}}})
        .exec(function(err,data){
    });
```